# Tabbar Controller to ViewController with backbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar controller implemented in my app, when i am fetching newsletter from server i have added a view controller in which i am showing the posts against that new'sletter the issue is i want the view controller back button so that user's can go back to tabbar controller. Below is the attached image of my issue,

I DON'T WANT TO EMBED NAVIGATION CONTROLLER.

[image: View Controller backbutton]

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to embed navigation controller,you may try to modal a view controller.and dismissController you view Controller back to tabor Controller,

[image]

[image]

Comment: @IBAction func back(sender: UIButton) {

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }